# Count occurrences of values, like @@?

Tags: javascript

I have created an expandable textarea. The number of characters of the content are counted and the row numbers of the textarea is calculated and modified.  This works really well.  But, when the user manually hits enter, which is a single character, no row is added.

I want to change it so that users can create their own paragraphs by adding @@ before a new paragraph.  This will be saved to a database. When I output it from the database, I'll replace the @@ with `<br /><br />`.

Here's the function I am using to calculate the row numbers:

```
function getRowCount(NumCharacters) {
    var NewRows = NumCharacters / 40;
    NewRows = parseInt(NewRows) + 1;
    return NewRows;
}
```

There are 40 characters per row. Each time the user hits another 40 characters, another row is added.

In my JavaScript, when a user hits @@, I need to ad an extra row to the row count.

How do I using JavaScript to search and count the number of times I find the @@ sequence? and add a row for each time?

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have tried a few of the answers below. Two of them work really well and are readable and simple.  Both, though, produce an error that I can't quite work around. Firebug tells me:

```
ThisText.match(/@@/g) is null
```

Yeah, I KNOW it's null. There's no @@'s to be found.

This throws an error:

```
var MyString = "Would you like to help me today?";
ExtraRows = MyString.match(/@@/g).length + 1;
```

This does NOT throw an error:

```
var MyString = "Would you like to @@help me today?";
ExtraRows = MyString.match(/@@/g).length + 1;
```

So, how do I get rid of the error that seems to occur when there are no @@'s to be found?

Comment: Have you tried setting `wrap=hard` on the `textarea`? This will cause the `textarea` to send newlines to the server. `<TEXTAREA NAME="HARD" COLS=40 ROWS=5 WRAP=HARD>`

Comment: No, I haven't tried wrap="hard" yet. I have the feeling I am going to check it out right about NOW!!!

Comment: You still have to manually insert a line break at every 40th character, but at least you'll escape the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it:

```
// Simplest, suggested
var lines = (str.match(/@@/g) || []).length + 1;

// One silly variation
var lines = 1;
str.replace(/@@/g,function(){ lines++ })

// Another silly variation
for (var lines=1,r=/@@/g;r.exec(str);lines++){}

// aka...
var lines=1,r=/@@/g;
while(r.exec(str)){ lines++ }
```

As an aside, for your initial function, I would write it more simply as:

```
function getRowCount(charCount) {
  return Math.ceil(charCount/40);
}
```

**Edit**: I've updated my initial answer with a simple inline way of guarding against the case when the `str` contains no `@@` at all.

Comment: I'm more than a little confused by this...  not a comment on your code - a comment on why method invocation should be allowed as a replace parameter....

Comment: @Brian: Normally the function should return the replacement. The arguments to the function are the matched strings and values of possible capture groups (afaik).

Comment: @Brian see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Yeah, again, not a knock on your code - a knock on JS standard that this works... :)  Just not intuitive based on the signature...  replace(toReplace,replaceWith).

Comment: @Evik See my update for one way to handle the case when `str.match()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "This is paragraph one@@and paragraph two@@and another";
var pcount = str.match(/@@/g).length;
```

Comment: true, but this is little different and and is a little more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You were right, but the other guy provided a bunch of extra examples to help me out.